# Web based subversion tool for browsingr/checkout/update/commit

Tags: svn

I am looking for a web based subversion browser and checkout/update/commit tool.

The repository is on a Linux server, but my development directory is on a different remote Linux server that does not have a GUI interface and I connect to it using SSH.

So what I do now is use svn update/commits. I use other tools (e.g. komodo) to edit the source code via SFTP, test and then commit through the command line.

Websvn is nice but is only for browsing. I am not looking to administer the repository either.  Just the typical svn commands (update/commit/diff/revert...etc)

Thanks

Comment: See the VisualSVN Server Web Interface demo at https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only basic functionality, why not to stick with command line?
It's pretty easy to use and you will learn it fast.

Use `svn help *command*` if you forgot syntax and `svn help` for list of commands.

Also there is a very good handbook (reading chapter 2 will be enough for basic usage):
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html

See also answers to this question for the list of some available web-based clients:
[What is the best web based Subversion client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137540/what-is-the-best-web-based-subversion-client)